# Ionic onfocusout event equivalent

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

In Ionic v3 there is an equivalent of `onfocus` called `(ionFocus)`.

For example to check on focus for an ion button it will be:

```
<button ion-button (ionFocus)="checkFocus()">Click Me</button>
```

I was wondering if there was an equivalent for `onfocusout`.

---

I tired:

```
 <button ion-button (ionFocusout)="checkFocus()">Click Me</button>
```

But that did not work.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

A more ionic way can be using ionic's ionBlur event which will fire an event whenever the selected element looses focus (i have used it on input and search bar but not on buttons yet)

```
  (ionBlur)="checkFocus()"
```

Comment: Is there a way to stop the on focus with ionBlur and only use the lost focus?

Answer (score 0):

In case of noob  like I was

```
     <ion-item no-lines>
        <ion-label stacked>My Label</ion-label>
        <ion-input
          type="text"
          placeholder="My place holder..."
          (ionFocus)="setInputFocus()"
          (ionBlur)="unCheckFocus()"
          [(ngModel)]="myInputValue">
        </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

***In typeScript file***

```
   setInputFocus() {
      console.log("Input box is active");
   }

  unCheckFocus() {
      console.log("Input box is Deactive");
  }
```